# Can \totvalue be called in the preamble?

Tags: counters, preamble, totalcount

I am trying to use the `totcount` package, and I noticed some strange behaviour I cannot explain.

With the following MWE :

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{totcount}

\newtotcounter{mycount}

\let\oldsec=\section
\def\section{\stepcounter{mycount}\oldsec}

\newcounter{testcount}
\setcounter{testcount}{\totvalue{mycount}}
\begin{document}
\total{mycount} \\
\arabic{testcount}


\section{First section header}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Second section header}
\lipsum[2]


\end{document}
```

even after several compilations, `\total{mycount}` prints `2` as expected, while `\arabic{testcount}` prints `-1`.

However, if I add `\AtBeginDocument` around `\setcounter{}{}` then the two commands are printing `2`, which is the expected behaviour.

Maybe I missed some point in the `totcount` package documentation, but is there any reason why one cannot use `totvalue` in the preamble ?

Comment: `totcount` uses the `.aux` file which is only read at `\begin{document}`.

Comment: @egreg : Ok, that makes sense now!  Thank you. A naïve question : what if in the preamble I define other commands using totvalue. It does not matter  because these commands will be expanded only at the moment they are called?

Comment: Note that redefining `\section` that way means that also `\section*` increments `mycount`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a good reason: the only way LaTeX has for saving values during a run for using them during the next one is via some auxiliary file.

The `totcount` package uses the standard `.aux` file, which is a very reasonable choice, as this file is always written (unless `\nofiles` has been declared) and read in at the start (and at the end, for making a comparison and issuing warning, if necessary).

However there's a catch: the first reading happens as part of `\begin{document}` and there's a good reason also for this: its contents can be interpreted only when all packages have been loaded, because some of them define things that can find their place in the file (`hyperref` is a prime example).

The `\totvalue` command is defined in such a way that it returns –1 if the value has not yet been established (which always happens when the counter has just been declared). So the behavior you describe is expected.

Use `\AtBeginDocument`, which is executed after the reading of the `.aux` file for setting a counter using `\totvalue`.

Defining a command in terms of `\totvalue` is safe, provided the command is only used in the document, because `\newcommand` doesn't interpret the replacement text, it just stores it unchanged. The `\totvalue` macro will be expanded when the command is used.

Actually, there is a way for reading the total value in the preamble, but it involves using a different auxiliary file. On the other hand, I still believe that doing the setting at begin document is cleaner.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{totcount}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtotcounter[auxfile=\jobname.tot]{mycount}

\newcounter{testcount}
\setcounter{testcount}{\totvalue{mycount}}

\preto\section{\stepcounter{mycount}}

\begin{document}

\total{mycount} \\
\arabic{testcount}

\section{First section header}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Second section header}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

**See the new version with `xassoccnt` at the end**

This uses the `assoccnt` package which associates counters to a driver counter, here the `section` counter as the master and `mycount` as the driven counter, which is stepped each time `section` is stepped as well, regardless whether `section` is reset in between. This does not require to redefine `\section` then.

At the end of the document, the total number of sections is stored to `totalsections`.

It should be possible to use `\AtBeginDocument{` in order to set the counter however, even with `totcount` counters, since this should be executed *after* `.aux` file has been read.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{assoccnt}
\newcounter{mycount}

\newcounter{totalsections}

\DeclareAssociatedCounters{section}{mycount}

\makeatletter
\AtEndDocument{%
  \immediate\write\@auxout{\string\setcounter{totalsections}{\number\value{mycount}}}
}%
\newcounter{anothercounter}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \setcounter{anothercounter}{\value{totalsections}} % Not really needed here, but works ;-)
}

\begin{document}
There are \arabic{totalsections} in this document


\section{First section header}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Second section header}
\lipsum[2]


\end{document}
```

**Version with xassoccnt, much shorter**

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{xassoccnt}


\NewTotalDocumentCounter{totalsections}

\DeclareAssociatedCounters{section}{totalsections}

\begin{document}
There are \TotalValue{totalsections} sections in this document


\section{First section header}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Second section header}
\lipsum[2]


\end{document}
```

**Update No 2**

With `xassoccnt v1.2` it is possible to simplify the counter definition a little bit:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{xassoccnt}


% Defines totalsections as a counter and associates it to section
\DeclareTotalAssociatedCounters{section}{totalsections}

\begin{document}
There are \TotalValue{totalsections} sections in this document


\section{First section header}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Second section header}
\lipsum[2]


\end{document}
```